# How can I transform XML document into target XML template structure (reduced attributes/elements) using Java

Tags: java, xml, post, xslt

I am looking for a way to transform an XML based on xml template provided by user.
I have a springboot service which is generating an output, 
here is a bsic sample but there are further nested elements under "Product" tag with charges taxes etc as well for that line item...

1. Entity Classes

***OrderHeader***

```
package com.example.microservice.dao;    

import java.util.List;    

import javax.persistence.Column;    
import javax.persistence.Entity;    
import javax.persistence.Id;    
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;    
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;    
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;    
import javax.persistence.Table;    

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;    

@Entity    
@Table(name="ORDER_HEADER")    
public class OrderHeader {    
    @Id    
    @Column(name="ORDER_HEADER_KEY", nullable=false)    
    private String orderHeaderKey;    
    @Column(name="ORDER_NO", nullable=false)    
    private String orderNo;    
    @Column(name="ENTERPRISE_KEY", nullable=false)    
    private String enterpriseKey;    
    @Column(name="SHIP_TO_KEY", nullable=false)    
    private String shipToKey;
    @Column(name="PAYMENT", nullable=false)    
    private String payment;     
    @Column(name="AUTHORISED", nullable=false)    
    private String authorised;      
    @Column(name="CUSTOMER", nullable=false)    
    private String customer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="oHeader")    
    private List<OrderLine> orderlines;    

    public OrderHeader() {    
        super();    
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub    
    }    
    public OrderHeader(String orderHeaderKey, String orderNo, String enterpriseKey, String shipToKey) {    
        super();    
        this.orderHeaderKey = orderHeaderKey;    
        this.orderNo = orderNo;    
        this.enterpriseKey = enterpriseKey;    
        this.shipToKey = shipToKey;    
    }       
// Getters & Setters    
//To String method override    
}
```

***OrderLine*** Entity class

```
package com.example.microservice.dao;    

import java.util.List;    
import javax.persistence.Column;    
import javax.persistence.Entity;    
import javax.persistence.Id;    
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;    
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;    
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;    
import javax.persistence.Table;    

@Entity    
@Table(name="ORDER_LINE")    
public class OrderLine {        
    @Id    
    @Column(name="ORDER_LINE_KEY")    
    private String orderLineKey;    
    @Column(name="ORDER_HEADER_KEY")    
    private String orderHeaderKey;    
    @Column(name="ITEM_ID")    
    private String itemID;    
    @Column(name="PRIME_LINE_NO")    
    private String primeLineNo;    
    @Column(name="ORDERED_QTY")    
    private String orderedQty;    
    @Column(name="LINE_TOTAL")    
    private String lineTotal;       
    @ManyToOne    
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_HEADER_KEY",referencedColumnName="ORDER_HEADER_KEY", insertable=false, updatable=false)    
    private OrderHeader oHeader;    

// Geters & Setters    
// To String override    
}
```

2. MicroService Controller method

   ```
   @RestController    
   public class MicroServiceController {    

   @Autowired    
   OrderHeaderRepository orderHeaderRepo;    
   @Autowired    
   OrderLineRepository orderLineRepo;    

   public MicroServiceController() {    
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub    
   }    


   @RequestMapping(path="/order/{orderID}",    
           method= {RequestMethod.POST})    
    public List<OrderHeader>  orderInfoID(@PathVariable(name="orderID") String orderID, @RequestBody String userPreferedTemplate) {    
       System.out.println("API output template from user----->"+userPreferedTemplate);    

       List<OrderHeader> oH = orderHeaderRepo.findByOrderHeaderKey(orderID);    
       System.out.println("JPA Query output for order entity \n"+oH.toString());    

       return oH;    
   }    

   }
   ```
3. The response to above code is as below, its returning entire attributes in order and product level.

```html
    <Order OrderNumber="223344" Customer="Bob" Payment="CreditCard" Authorised="Y">    
    <Product Line="1" ProductId="Item_1001" Quantity="2.00" LineTotal="200"  />    
    <Product Line="2" ProductId="Item_1002" Quantity="2.00" LineTotal="400"  />    
    <Product Line="3" ProductId="Item_1003" Quantity="2.00" LineTotal="600"  />       
    </Order>
```

4. User is sending a POST request to the endpoint along with template specifying attributes it is interested in:

POSTMAN_REQ_IMAGE

[image]

User requested attributes in return

```
<Order OrderNumber="" >
<Product Line="" ProductId="" />
</Order>
```

5. Based on the template coming from webservice user in step4, is it possible to trim the output in step2 controller method, and send only matching elements & attributes in response.

```html
    <Order OrderNumber="223344" >       
    <Product Line="1" ProductId="Item_1001" />    
    <Product Line="2" ProductId="Item_1002" />    
    <Product Line="3" ProductId="Item_1003" />    
    <Product Line="4" ProductId="Item_1004" />      
    </Order>
```

** if user passes an invalid tag in template

```
<Order OrderNumber="" >
<ProductLINESSSS Line="" ProductId="" />
</Order>
```

then such tags would be ignored and output should look like

```
<Order OrderNumber="223344" > 
</Order>
```

The reason for this is Order as an entity has relationships with products, shipping address, billing address etc, payments...
for user who wants retrieve customer info using order# , rest of info of product, address, payment is not relevant.
for applications, who wish to retrieve product can provide template accordingly.

Also

I am not sure if JPA has something to achieve this or an xslt transformation could do it but would appreciate inputs on right approach to achieve this.

Comment: Is it ensured that the structures of both XML documents match? Can there be elements having text children as well?

Comment: Add a [mcve] with a good description of where the problem is in your code

Comment: So nothing to do with the JPA API. This is simply convert some XML doc into java objects

Comment: @kozmo : Added sample code.

Comment: @MartinHonnen : They should match, unidentified elements and attributes in user template can be ignored. i updated info in step 5.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt : I updated details, apologies that my question was not very brief.. still new on forum :)

Comment: @BillyFrost : probably, but wasnt sure if JPA can address something like this.

Comment: JPA is to persist JAVA OBJECTS to a DATABASE. End of

Comment: Thanks @BillyFrost .

Can anyone help if this can be achieved via a transformation logic using an xslt or java code ?